# Как убрать отступ у последнего item-a горизонтального RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, divider

Не могу справиться с отступом последнего элемента своего горизонтального `RecycleraView`
Находил в интернете код переопределения ItemDecoration() для удаления последнего отступа, но все они были для вертикального `RecyclerView` и не подошли мне.

Заранее благодарю.

Прилагаю найденный код:

```
public class DividerItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private Drawable mDivider;

    public DividerItemDecorator(Drawable divider) {
        mDivider = divider;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int dividerLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int dividerRight = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i <= childCount - 2; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int dividerTop = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int dividerBottom = dividerTop + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(dividerLeft, dividerTop, dividerRight, dividerBottom);
            mDivider.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По идее найденный вами код должен работать, надо только поменять чуть логику - вместо низа использовать право.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, Вы правы. Но к сожалению, я не смог разобраться в найденом коде.. Не могли бы Вы помочь с этим?

Comment: Возможно, вам можно вот такое попробовать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62124845/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Увы, этот способ не работает. Но спасибо.